# How to use Node.js to build pages that are a mix between static and dynamic content?

Tags: node.js

All pages on my 5 page site should be output using a Node.js server.

Most of the page content is static. At the bottom of each page, there is a bit of dynamic content.

My node.js code currently looks like:

```
var http = require('http'); 

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    console.log('request starting...');

    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });

    var html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>My Title</title></head><body>';
    html += 'Some more static content';
    html += 'Some more static content';
    html += 'Some more static content';
    html += 'Some dynamic content';
    html += '</body></html>';

    response.end(html, 'utf-8');

}).listen(38316);
```

I'm sure there are numerous things wrong about this example. Please enlighten me!
For example:

- How can I add static content to the
  page without storing it in a string as a variable value with += numerous times?
- What is the best practices way to build a small site in Node.js where all pages are a mix between static and dynamic content?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Personally, I'd use a server that has higher level constructs. For instance, take a look at the expressjs framework - http://expressjs.com/

The constructs you'll be interested in from this package are:

- Truly static files (assets etc): app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
- A templating language such as jade, mustache, etc:

  - http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html
  - https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/
  - You'll want to look up 'locals' and 'partials' for embedding small bits of dynamic content in mostly static content

For example in jade:

```
!!! 5
html(lang="en")
  head
    title= pageTitle
    script(type='text/javascript')
      if (foo) {
         bar()
      }
  body
    h1 Jade - node template engine
    #container
      - if (youAreUsingJade)
        p You are amazing
      - else
        p Get on it!
```

Becomes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Jade</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      if (foo) {
        bar()
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Jade - node template engine</h1>
    <div id="container">
      <p>You are amazing</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you prefer something a little less *drastic* I would say look at mustache or one of the other engines that looks a bit more like regular-sauce html.

Comment: I ended up using express with ejs. I created the dynamic content on app.js (file created by express express) var foo = "bar".... Then I added the  dynamic content in the app.js file in the statement: res.render('index', { my_dynamic_content: foo }); ... Then I added the content to my html page (index.ejs) with <%= my_dynamic_content %>

Comment: Second link is broken.

Answer (score 8):

Alternative you can just use [jsDOM](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom). This means you have a DOM object you can manipulate on the server to add your dynamic content, then you can just flush the DOM as a HTML file / string

Answer (score 6):

These days the answer is not so straightforward.

If you don't need to be indexed by Google, consider making a single-page application using `socket.io` and client-side templates such as `jQuery Templates`. There are even emerging node.js frameworks for this type of architecture, e.g. `socketstream`.

If you need to be indexed by Google, do you need your dynamic content to be indexed? If yes, 
consider using `express` and server-side templates such as `ejs`, `jade` or `mustache`. Another (discouraged) approach might be to generate XML from JSON on server and use an XSLT front-end.

If you need only static content to be indexed, consider using `express` on server, but don't generate any dynamic HTML on server. Instead, send your dynamic content in JSON format to client using AJAX or socket.io, and render it using client-side templates such as `jQuery Templates`.

Don't consider server-side DOM: DOM doesn't scale for complex layouts, you will sink in a sea of selectors and DOM calls. Even client-side developers understood that and implemented client-side templates. A new promising approach is `weld` library. It offers best of both worlds, but it is not mature yet to be used in production (e.g. simple things like conditional rendering are not supported yet).

Answer (score 4):

One good way is to use a templating engine.  You can store the templates as separate files, and the templating engine has the ability to make the content dynamic.  Personally I use yajet (http://www.yajet.net/) which is written for the web but works fine with node, and there are numerous template engines for node on npm.

Answer (score 4):

One of the best things I found is to use NodeJS, Express and Mustache...

You can create your HTML pages as you normally would using Mustache syntax for placeholders for your variables {{name}}...

When a user hits your site, express routs the slug to the correct template...
NodeJS get's the file...
NodeJS get's the dataset from a DB...
Run it through Mustache on the server...
Send the completed page to the client...

Here is a scaled back version I wrote on my blog.  It's simple but the idea is pretty sound.  I use it to quickly deploy pages on my site.

http://devcrapshoot.com/javascript/nodejs-expressjs-and-mustachejs-template-engine

I went this route because I didn't want to learn all of the extra syntax to write a language I already knew (html).  It makes more sense and follows more of a true MVC pattern.

Answer (score 1):

First deliver only static HTML files from server to the client. Then use something like AJAX / server.io to serve the dynamic content. IMO Jade is really ugly for writing HTML code and its better to use a template engine.

I did some Google and found some code by this fellow, its good if you are doing it for PoC / learning.

```
var server = require('./server'); 
var controller = require("./controller"); 
var urlResponseHandlers = require("./urlResponseHandlers");   

var handle = {};   
handle["/"] = urlResponseHandlers.fetch; 
handle["/fetch"] = urlResponseHandlers.fetch; 
handle["/save"] = urlResponseHandlers.save;   
server.start(controller.dispatch, handle);
```

Here is how the logic for handling URLs is displayed -

```
var staticHandler = require('./staticHandler');

function dispatch(handler, pathname, req, res) {
  console.log("About to dispatch a request for " + pathname);
  var content = "Hey " + pathname;
  if (typeof handler[pathname] === 'function') {
      content += handler[pathname](req);
      res.writeHead(200, {
          'Content-Type': 'text/html'
      });
      res.write(content);
      res.end();
  } else {
      console.log("No request handler found for " + pathname);
      staticHandler.handleStatic(pathname, res);
  }
```

}

Here is how static files can be handled -

```
function handleStatic(pageUrl, response) {
    var filename = path.join(process.cwd(), pageUrl);
    path.exists(filename, function (exists) {
        if (!exists) {
            console.log("not exists: " + filename);
            response.writeHead(404, {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html'
            });
            response.write('404 Not Found\n');
            response.end();
            return;
        }
        //Do not send Content type, browser will pick it up. 
        response.writeHead(200);
        var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
        fileStream.on('end', function () {
            response.end();
        });
        fileStream.pipe(response);
        return;
    });
}
exports.handleStatic = handleStatic;
```

I liked the idea. All code copied from [this link](http://roadtobe.com/supaldubey/extending-our-nodejs-static-dynamic-server/)!
.

Answer (score 1):

A solution have found to this, without using any other modules and or other script is to make the calling script into a module and include it with the function `require()`. 
[With this solution I can use javascript which ever way I want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068683/how-execute-a-javascript-in-a-node-js-server/22140414#22140414)
What I would do is make an ajax call to a nodejs script (www.example.com/path/script.js)
script.js would need to be built like a module with the `exports.functionName=function(){...}`
After that include it in your webserver function `require(pathToTheScript).functionName(res,req)`
You will also need to end the response in the functionName(res,req) by doing res.end();