# How execute a javascript in a node.js server

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I have written a node.js server.
I am able to extract the HTTP POST and GET variable from the request.
I would like to pass those variable to the js script on the server to be executed.
In PHP to execute a script I would just point to it @ www.example.com/path/file.php?variable=value

```
<?php echo "You have ".$_GET['variable'];?>
```

I want to achieve the same with noge.js @ www.example.com/path/file.njs?variable=value
My problem is the file.njs is executed as a text.
I am not using express, a solution without it would be appreciated.

```
 var sys=require("sys"),
 http=require("http"),
 path=require("path"),
 url=require("url"),
 filesys=require("fs"),
 mime=require("./node_modules/mime"),
 head=require("./node_modules/headers/initreq.njs");//this is used to extract the header
 http.createServer(handler).listen(80);//handler function is below
 sys.puts("Node Server Running on 80");

 function handler(request,response){
    var myPath=url.parse(request.url).pathname;//get the url
    var ext=myPath.replace(/(.)*\./,'');//get the extension
    var fullPath=path.join(process.cwd(),myPath);//get the working dir & join it with current working dir
    var mimeResult=mime.lookup(fullPath),acceptExt=['html','njs'];  

    if(acceptExt.indexOf(ext)!=-1){//only search HTTP header for html|njs files
        head.init(request,response,setContent);//head will correctly contain the $_GET AND $_POST variable
    } else {setContent();}  

    function setContent(){
        path.exists(fullPath,function(exists){
            if(!exists){
                response.writeHeader(404, {"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
                response.write("404 Not Found:: "+fullPath+"\n");
                response.end();
            }else{
                filesys.readFile(fullPath,"binary",function(err,file){
                    if(err){
                        response.writeHeader(500,{"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
                        response.write(err+"::"+myPath+"\n");
                        response.end();
                    }else{                      
                        response.setHeader("Content-Type", mimeResult);
                        response.writeHeader(200);
                        response.write(file,"binary");//this is the file that i want to execute and pass the $_POST & $_GET variable
                        response.end();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
   sys.puts("Requested:: "+myPath.replace(/(.)*\//,'')+" - "+mimeResult );   
 }
```

Comment: The **XY problem** http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem#answer-66378

Comment: okay @David granted I am thinking like a php developer. How would this be solved then? am wrong to think node.js can be used like PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In summary what I wanted to achieve is use node.js like PHP.
to execute a PHP file like
www.example.com/path/file.php?variable=value
With node.js
www.example.com/path/file.js?variable=value
The solution I have come up with is to make the requested javascript into a module and include it with the function `require`.
e.g.

```
http.createServer(function(req,res){
   var myPath=url.parse(req.url).pathname;//get the url
   var fullPath=path.join(process.cwd(),myPath);//get the working dir & join it with current working dir
    require(fullPath).content(req,res);//this is where the requested script is executed as a module. make sure to end the response (response.end()) in the module
});
```

Though not thoroughly tested this solution works for me and I can use it even for dynamic pages.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a URL parameter named `variable`. I think this would work:

```
var parameters = url.parse(request.url, true);
var variable = parameters.variable;
```

I haven't used node.js in a while, but I'm pretty sure this works.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know what your code chunk is supposed to do, but here is a basic **Hello World** for you that prints out a get parameter:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  var params = url.parse(request.url, true);
  response.end("You have " + params.query.variable);
});

server.listen(8000);
```

Now just visit `127.0.0.1:8000/?variable=foo`